# Need help for .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying to setup a RewriteRule for my .htaccess to redirect any not found .php url to my loader.php ... For some reasons, it's redirecting even if the file exist.

Here's what I have:

```
# Engine On for Extension Removal
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the url for the login page
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?tab=login [NC,L]

# Load the url with the page loader if the url doesn't match any of the rule above
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ loader.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# Remove PHP Extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Everything is working before I added this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ loader.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Right now, no matter what is in my link, even if it exist or not, it'll load the loader.php. And I have other rules like the login one, same thing but different name which is why I didn't bother posting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
# Engine On for Extension Removal
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the url for the login page
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?tab=login [NC,L]


# Remove PHP Extensio

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ loader.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ loader.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

is that it accepts any .php url  in the request and rewrites it to loader.php.

The condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

change this behaviour of the rule, it tells server to process the rule only when there is a request for non existent php file.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! :)

Comment: Just a curious question, what is the !-d for? I'm supposing then -f is if it finds the file, and !-f is if it doesn't find the file?